# Rasa: Borfront compability troubleshooting

Tags: spacy, rasa, spacy-3

I use an open source product - Botfront, which uses Rasa version 2.3.3 and Rasa SDK 2.3.1. I need to train a model in Russian using Spacy NLP. By default, Spacy version 2.2.4 is installed in the Rasa image, while the Russian language is available starting from version 3.x.x. There is a problem when updating Spacy because the “link” command used by botfront is deprecated. How can I manually connect a model in spact 3.x.x

I tried copying the model to the sapcy/data directory, but it didn't give any results.